# How can I prove that $PSL(2,3)\simeq A_4$?

Tags: finite-groups, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism, exceptional-isomorphisms

I would like to prove that $PSL(2,3) \simeq A_4$.

I know the structure of $SL(2,3)$ and that $A_4=V\rtimes C_3$, where $V$ is the Klein subgroup.

How can I proceed?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: See [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/PSL(2,3)_is_isomorphic_to_A4). First show that $PGL(2,3)$ is isomorphic to $S_4$ (also proved at the link).

Comment: [Homework $4.$](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~cossey/611%20hw%204.pdf) is exactly your question. The hints are very good there.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you!